# How can I define primitives in StandardStyles.xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8, styles, .net-4.5, windows-store-apps

I want to define double values so that I can reuse it in many `UIElements`

```
<Double x:Key="MyWidth">100</Double>
<String x:Key="MyString">This is my text</String>
```

It's giving me error **`Double is not supported in a Windows App project.`** and same is for string.

And if I include **`xmlns:sys="using:System"`** in StandardStyles.xaml then it's compiling.

```
<sys:Double x:Key="MyWidth">100</sys:Double>
<sys:String x:Key="MyString">This is my text</sys:String>
```

It's giving exception at runtime **`XAML Parsing Failed. The type 'Double' was not found.`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no need of including **`System`** namespace.
There is already a namespace included **`xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`**

```
<x:Double x:Key="MyWidth">100</x:Double>
<x:String x:Key="MyString">This is my text</x:String>
```

Comment: For some reason, this doesn't work. I get the error "Double is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project." I'm on .NET 4.0.

Comment: Pompair can't say why you're facing this issues, I haven't code for win since last year